# Where does winsock store ip address of a socket?

Tags: c++, winsock

Suppose I have a simple winsock server that has a listening socket, and then when a connection is accepted, it stores the socket in an array of sockets (to allow multiple connections).
How can I get the IP address of a specific connection? Is it stored in the socket handle?

Comment: Sidenote: the socket handle is more or less just a typedef for an integer variable. On *nix the programmer uses an actual int to keep track of the handles.

Comment: Nothing is "stored in the handle"; it's just a handle, not an object! It refers to an in-kernel object though (which you obviously can't access directly), and that does track the relevant IP addresses. getsockname/getpeername calls into the kernel and retrieves the field for the address corresponding to the handle passed in (the SOCKET int is mapped by WinSock to an underlying HANDLE, because Windows is barmy and can't just use fds and simple syscalls like everyone else).

Answer (score 8):

As long, as the socket stays connected, you can get both own socket address and peer one.

**getsockname** will give you local name (i.e. from your side of a pipe)
**getpeername** will give you peer name (i.e. distant side of a pipe)

This information is available only when the socket is opened/connected, so it is good to to store it somewhere if it can be used after peer disconnects.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is stored in the `socketaddr_in` struct, you can extract it using:

```
SOCKADDR_IN client_info = {0};
int addrsize = sizeof(client_info);

// get it during the accept call
SOCKET client_sock = accept(serv, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, &addrsize);

// or get it from the socket itself at any time
getpeername(client_sock, &client_info, sizeof(client_info));

char *ip = inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr);

printf("%s", ip);
```

Comment: Some comments/corrections: 0 Does `SOCKADDR_IN` really exist? 1 It's `sockaddr_in` not `socketaddr_in`. 2 You are missing to pass the address of `client_info` (two times); 3 `client` isn't declared. 4 `accept()` expects a third parameter! At least 4 inaccuracies -> -1

Comment: @thanks for the corrections. I'll edit the answer to contain them. This answer was extracted from the linked stack-overflow answer and i'll admit i didn't check it 100%. Also, the answer is in context to the question. Client doesn't need to be declared in this example.

Comment: To have the example make sense I feel `client.sin_addr` shall read `client_info.sin_addr`.

Comment: Ok, and finally: `accept(serv, &client_info, &addrsize);` will through two type mismatch related warnings. The first is a pointer type mismatch, the secoand an integer type mismatch. They typically are fixed by doing: `socklen_t addrsize = 0; accept(serv, (struct sockaddr *) &client_info, &addrsize);` **Update:** The latter is not an issue on windows if using the WINSOCK2 API, as `int*` is used here.