# How can I get the connected client's IP address using WinSock2 and C?

Tags: c, ip, client, winsock

I want to get the IP address of the client who’s just connected into my server running WinSock2. I’m using C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does winsock store ip address of a socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382316/where-does-winsock-store-ip-address-of-a-socket)

Comment: i was seeing this question everywhere but truly i couldn't get their solutions working for my case!

Comment: Then post the relevant bits of your actual code and describe _exactly_ what's not working with it. (Do that by [edit]ing your question.) (The second answer to the linked question contains an example snippet.)

Comment: Now it's working, i used inet_ntoa()    SOCKADDR_IN sinInfo;  .............  char* ip = inet_ntoa(sinInfo.sin_addr);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have not done it myself, but take a look at [getpeername](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Looks like this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, i hope i would be able to use it in WINSOCK2!

Answer (score 7):

You could get the client's IP-address and port via the call to [`accept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Just pass in the appropriate data into the last two parameters.

```
struct sockaddr_in sa = {0}; /* for TCP/IP */
socklen_t socklen = sizeof sa;
... = accept(..., (struct sockaddr *) &sa, &socklen);
```

For details [please read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: According to the documentation : "addrlen [in, out] An optional pointer to an integer that contains the length of structure pointed to by the addr parameter.". so the initilization of `socklen` is wrong it should be `socklen = sizeof(sockaddr)`, else `accept` will fail with error `WSAEFAULT`

Comment: @Mouin: Ups, yes, socklen needs to be initialised according the the size of the struct which's address is passed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me on **winsock2**. No need of **getpeername**

```
SOCKET newConnection;
SOCKADDR_IN addr;
int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);

char *ip = inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr);
printf("Accepted Connection from :  %s", ip);
```