# winsock2: How to get the ipv4/ipv6 address of a connected client after server side code calls `accept()`

Tags: windows, sockets, ipv6, ipv4, winsock2

There are other similar questions on this site, but they either do not related to winsock2 or they are suitable only for use with ipv4 address spaces. The default compiler for Visual Studio 2019 produces an error when the `ntoa` function is used, hence an ipv4 and ipv6 solution is required.

I did once produce the code to do this for a Linux system however I am currently at work and do not have access to that. It may or may not be "copy and paste"-able into a windows environment with winsock2. (Edit: I will of course add that code later this evening, but of course it might not be useful.)

The following contains an example, however this is an example for client side code, *not* server side code.

https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedInternet3c.html

Here, the `getaddrinfo()` function is used to obtain a structure containing matching ipv4 and ipv6 addresses. To obtain this information there is some interaction with DNS, which is not required in this case.

I have some server code which calls `accept()` (after bind and listen) to accept a client connection. I want to be able to print the client ip address and port to stdout.

The most closely related question on this site is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716092/how-can-i-get-the-connected-clients-ip-address-using-winsock2-and-c). However the answer uses `ntoa` and is only ipv4 compatible.

#### What I have so far:

So far I have something sketched out like this:

```
SOCKET acceptSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKADDR_IN addr; // both of these are NOT like standard unix sockets
    // I don't know how they differ and if they can be used with standard
    // unix like function calls (eg: inet_ntop)

int addrlen = sizeof addr;
acceptSocket = accept(listenSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
if(acceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // some stuff
}
else
{
    const std::size_t addrbuflen = INET6_ADDRSRTLEN;
    char addrbuf[addrbuflen] = '\0'
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void*)addr.sin_addr, (PSTR)addrbuf, addrbuflen);
    // above line does not compile and mixes unix style function calls
    // with winsock2 structures
    std::cout << addrbuf << ':' << addr.sin_port << std::endl;
}
```

#### getpeername()

```
int ret = getpeername(acceptSocket, addrbuf, &addrbuflen);
    // addrbuf cannot convert from char[65] to sockaddr*
if(ret == ???)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: but accept direct return such address. in what problem/question ?

Comment: @RbMm `accept()` returns a socket structure of some kind not an ascii string

Comment: yes, of course socket structure. and so what ?

Comment: `SOCKADDR_IN addr` here you guess that address is ipv4. you hardcode this. if what more generic - use `SOCKADDR_INET addr`. and look like you confuse  address and it string representation. address possible convert to string via `WSAAddressToString`.

Comment: @RbMm Sorry but I have absolutely no idea what you are saying here. Yes I use an ipv4 structure to hold the address. The only reason I am asking this is because `ntoa` is not supported in VS2019. The solution doesn't have to actually accept ipv6 addresses, it just has to use an `inet_ntop` or equivalent function.

Comment: @RbMm I don't know if that clarifies why I asked the question like this?

Comment: i already say - use `SOCKADDR_INET addr` instead `SOCKADDR_IN addr`. and *ntoa is not supported in VS2019* ))) vs<some version> here unrelated at all - vs - this is not OS. use `WSAAddressToString` if you want convert address to string

Comment: *I don't know if that clarifies why I asked the question like this?* - accept already return address to you. are you understand this ? you ask how got something, which api direct return

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the [`SOCKADDR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2). This is effectively a discriminated union. The first field tells you whether its an IPv4 (`==AF_INET`) or IPv6 (`==AF_INET6`) address. Depending on that you cast the `addr` pointer to be either `struct sockaddr_in*` or `struct sockaddr_in6*`, and then read off the IP address from the relevant field.

Comment: for what when accept already return this ?

Comment: See my added final paragraph, I am not sure how to use this function despite checking docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-getpeername

Comment: No, `accept` gives you a socket, which is a local structure akin to a file descriptor. `getPeerName` looks up the details of the machine at the other end of the connection represented by the socket, which is what you want.

Comment: @PaulJohnson - `getpeername` have the same output as `accept` - because this this call is senseless

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I missed the output sockaddr in `accept`. I'll try again.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Is he correct when he says (I think this is what he is saying) that the return value from `getpeeraddr()` is the same as the return value for `accept()`. I won't ask the second part to this question as is depends on the answer to this. As an aside, what is the point of `getpeeraddr()` if it returns the same thing as `accept()`? `getpeeraddr()` takes a socket as an argument, so this suggests to me that `getpeeraddr()` doesn't do anything useful, if what he says is correct.

Comment: I really don't think what he's saying is correct, unless I just don't understand what is being said https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-getpeername

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: It's not that `getpeeraddr()` is useless, simply that `accept()` will call it for you, if you provide a non-null buffer in arguments 2 and 3.  `getpeeraddr()` is still more capable because it can be used any time before the socket is closed, and not only at the moment of accepting a connection.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for clarifying that. Now I understand the point being made. Perhaps I should ask this as a separate question, but it will essentially be a duplicate: SOCKADDR is a non-standard (ie a windows) thing. Can it be used with `inet_ntop`. ie; Can I cast a `SOCKADDR` field to a `struct sockaddr_in*` ? It looks a bit odd, combining unix style sockets code with windows specific things.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant what i say is correct, whatever you think. you need pass large enough buffer to `accept` for get back sockaddr. `sockaddr_in` can hold only ipv4. for be prepare to ipv6 address - need pass how minimum `SOCKADDR_INET`. and for convert address to string need use `WSAAddressToString`

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: You can freely mix `sockaddr` and `SOCKADDR`.  If you visit the first link in this answer, you will see that `typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;` and likewise `typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;`  The only difference is that `sockaddr` is paired with the `struct` keyword (required in C, optional in C++) and `SOCKADDR` is never paired with the `struct` keyword.

Comment: @BenVoigt Helpful info, thanks. In this case it appears to be essentially the same as unix sockets in terms of function calls. If I have any further compile issues, I will ask as a separate question I suppose since the focus has changed somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

C++ code snippet in vs2019:

```
    char* CPortListener::get_ip_str(struct sockaddr* sa, char* s, size_t maxlen)
        {
            switch (sa->sa_family) {
            case AF_INET:
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr),
                    s, maxlen);
                break;
        
            case AF_INET6:
                inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr),
                    s, maxlen);
                break;
        
            default:
                strncpy(s, "Unknown AF", maxlen);
                return NULL;
            }
        
            return s;
        }

Example:


   
   {
         ...
         
         char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
         sockaddr_storage ca;
         socklen_t al = sizeof(ca);
         SOCKET recv = accept(sd, (sockaddr*)&ca, &al);
         pObj->m_ip = get_ip_str(((sockaddr*)&ca),s,sizeof(s));
    }
```